# Implementing 'new' in Rust

Tags: rust

When creating a new class, module (not sure what it's called in Rust), are we supposed to 'overload' the `new` function? See example below:

```
pub struct Person {
    name: String,
    email: String,
    age: i8,
    height: i16,
}

impl Person {
    pub fn new(name: String, age: i8, email: String, height: i16) -> Self {
        Self { name, age, email, height }
    }
}
```

So that when we try to create an object, the user can supply it as follows:

```
let p = Person::new("someName".to_string(), 120, "hello@gmail.com".to_string(), 200);
```

Or is this the wrong way to go about it in Rust?

Reading the official docs on [Constructors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/constructors.html), from what I gather, we aren't "overloading" anything; instead, there is no constructor. So I assume it's a convention to call you "constructors" `new`?

Comment: Yes, generally `YourType::new` should have an argument for each value needed to initialize an instance of the type.

Comment: My initial mistake was assuming that 'new' functioned like constructors you'd typically see in C++, Java or any other OOP programming language.

Comment: Yes, `new()` is a convention. The only built-in thing related to constructors is the [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) trait, which is recommended to be implemented if it makes sense for your struct.

Comment: @Randy Rust is not an OOP language, and `new()` does **not** construct a value on the heap (like the OOP languages you referenced). It creates a value on the stack. If you want to then move it onto the heap, you need to wrap it in `Box`.

Comment: *"not sure what it's called in rust"* - it's called a `struct` :P

Comment: For structs with many fields, you can also consider the [builder pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/creational/builder.html)